# Plotting graph from multiple .ivc files in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I have written a code to open multiple.ivc files, clean the data and plot the graph in a single plot. Unfortunately, my code is plotting data from one file even though I select multiple files.

my code is

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.image as image
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from tkinter import filedialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
files1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True) 
files = root.tk.splitlist(files1)
List = list(files) 

%gui tk
Str=''.join(List)
fname = Str.split('.')[0]
dic={}

for i,file in enumerate(List):
    d = open(file)
    for ln in d.readlines():
        ln = ln.strip()
        if ln.startswith('Volt') or \
        ln.startswith('Ref ') or \
        ln.startswith('Cur') or \
        ln.startswith('Raw ') or \
        ln.startswith('WPVS '):
            hdr=[h.strip() for h in ln.split(':')[:2]] # store headers
            dic[hdr[0]], dic[hdr[1]] = [], []
        elif dic != {} and ln != '':
            data = ln.split()   # split data
            dic[hdr[0]].append(data[0]) # add to data lists
            dic[hdr[1]].append(data[1])# trim whitespace
mxlen = 0
for k in dic: 
    if len(dic[k]) > mxlen: 
        mxlen = len(dic[k])
                
#print('Max column length',mxlen)

# fill in -1 to make columns same length
for k in dic: 
    dic[k].extend([0]*(mxlen-len(dic[k])))

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
df['Power'] = df['Voltage']*df['Current']

df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)

#plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax1 =ax.twinx()
ax.grid(True,axis='both')
#ax.set(xlabel="Voltage", ylabel="Current", title="IV Curve") 
ax.set_xlabel("Voltage [V]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.set_xlabel("Voltage [V]",fontsize = 20)
ax.set_ylabel("Current [I]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.set_ylabel("Power [W]",fontsize = 20)
ax1.spines['right'].set_color('red')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('red')
ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax1)
#ax.set_title("IV/PV Curve Plot",fontweight ='bold', fontsize = 30, color='blue')
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=20)
ax.set_ylim (0,4) #adjust the current limits
ax.set_xlim (0,70) #adjust the voltage limits
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=20)
ax1.set_ylim  (0,150) #adjust the power limits
ax1.set_xlim (0,70) #adjust the voltage limits

ax.plot('Voltage', 'Current', data=df, linewidth=4, label='IV curve')
ax1.plot('Voltage', 'Power', data=df, linewidth=4, color='r', label ='PV Curve')
ax.legend( loc='upper right',fontsize=20)
ax1.legend(loc='lower right',fontsize=20)
#pmax and Vmax

Pmax = df["Power"].max()
maxrow = df[df['Power']==Pmax]
Voltage = maxrow['Voltage'].iloc[0]
Current = maxrow['Current'].iloc[0]
xmax1 =(Voltage/70)
xmax2 =(Current/4)
ax.axhline(y=Current, xmin=0, xmax =xmax1,linewidth=4, color ='g',linestyle='--',)
ax.axvline(x=Voltage, ymin=0, ymax =xmax2, linewidth=4, color='g', linestyle='--')

#img = image.imread("/home/hebin/Desktop/PV/Mitsui/Flasher/logo.png")
#plt.figimage(img, 1380, 1150, alpha=1)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig(fname + ".png")

print(f'IV: {file}')
```

Link to sample data file:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sL2-CwCGeGm0-fvcpzMVzgFnYzN3wzVb?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a tab:

```
for i,file in enumerate(List):
    d = open(file)
    
    for ln in d.readlines(): ##<<-- added 4 spaces for this block
        ln = ln.strip()
        if ln.startswith('Volt') or \
        ln.startswith('Ref ') or \
        ln.startswith('Cur') or \
        ln.startswith('Raw ') or \
        ln.startswith('WPVS '): # start new lists
            hdr=[h.strip() for h in ln.split(':')[:2]] # store headers
            dic[hdr[0]], dic[hdr[1]] = [], []  # start new list
        elif dic != {} and ln != '':  # check if data row
            data = ln.split()   # split data
            dic[hdr[0]].append(data[0]) # add to data lists
            dic[hdr[1]].append(data[1])# trim whitespace
        # check for header row
```

Maybe this will work, although I am not sure your question is general enough...